# Generating numerical filenames for two different ranges

Tags: python

I have 30,000 files in a folder. start from `0` to `30000`. I want to read from start to end with `10` interval when end number is higher than `5000`. I have created following code,

```
startFile = 0
endFile = 5000

for k in range(startFile, endFile + 1):
    execfile(read_path + str(k) + ".py")
```

This code read my file `0` to `5000`. But i need it to read at an interval of 10 when `endfile` is larger than `5000`. So there must be 2 conditions, one for `endfile` less or equal to `5000` it will read `0` to `5000` and one for `endfile` higher than `5000` where the program will read with an interval of `10`. Any idea how to write it in python?

Comment: Do you mean something like 'in chunks of 10 file' or every 10th file. Latter can be easily solved by adding a 3rd argument (step) to your for loop. `if endfile >= 500: for k in range(startFile, endFile+1, 10)`

Comment: Isn't this question about generating strings?

Comment: @umutto every 10th file. as 30000 files contain load of data i need the program to escape some file. as i can modify endFile it is better to have both condition at the same time one for endfile<=5000 and one for endFile>5000

Comment: @Peter Wood I am not sure about it as I am new in programming.

Comment: @TanvirHossain Okay, I think I got what you want to do and I made my comment a bit more clearer and write as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the number of files in a directory by using [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir);

```
>>> import os
>>> n_files = len(os.listdir(read_path))
>>> n_files 
74
```

Once you do that, you can choose your stepsize and process every 10th file by giving step argument to range;

```
>>> startFile = 0
>>> endFile = 5000

>>> step = 1 if n_files <= endFile else 10

>>> for k in range(startFile, endFile + 1, step):
>>>     execfile(read_path + str(k) + ".py")
```

For reference [range](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) (start, stop, step) arguments. Step is the index increment size, it will pick the **n**'th next element if you set it as **n**.

```
>>> [i for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Comment: Instead of introducing n_file can I directly write,  step = 1 if endFile <= 5000 else 10
for k in range(startFile, endFile + 1, step):
execfile(read_path + str(k) + ".py")

Comment: @TanvirHossain yes you can, I used n_files for easier readability. But in your comment `endfile <= 5000` will always be true, since you initialized it as so. Do you want to replace `n_files` with `len(os.listdir(read_path))`?

Comment: actually i dont need n_file as i can define numbers according to my need. it can be 100 or 1000 or 10000. I just need to introduce my step here for two different cases to reduce simulation time.

Comment: @TanvirHossain If you know the number of files and want to explicitly present the number. You don't need to use os.listdir, I've included that so it would be a bit more dynamic. You can just do if - else check and adjust the step size accordingly.

Comment: @umotto Yes I have to define the number of start and end file. I use step=1 and it works fine but for step=10 I am getting this 'error index 70 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 61'

Comment: @TanvirHossain I don't think you are getting that error because of range function. Can you check if your execfile works with k = 70.